# MySQL save row before delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have some tables:

```
Table1
id | some_field_1 | some_field_2
---|--------------|-------------
 1 |    data1     |    data2
 2 |    data3     |    data4

Table2
id | othr_field_1 | othr_field_2 | othr_field_3
---|--------------|--------------|-------------
 1 |    data5     |    data6     |   data7
 2 |    data8     |    data9     |   data10
```

I don't know field names and count in tables.

Also have `history` table:

```
id | table_name | table_id | data
---|------------|----------|-----
```

Now before deleting row from my tables I need to save it in `history` table so in `data` field saved my row in some string format like `JSON`, `XML` or etc.

It's possible to do with PHP but is it possible with `BEFORE DELETE` trigger?

Something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg
BEFORE DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

        INSERT INTO history
        (table_name, table_id, data)
        values ( 'table1', OLD.id, SOME_FUNCTION(OLD));

END
$$
```

What need to be instead of `SOME_FUNCTION`?

Comment: Do you really need to delete it at all? Could you just have a status flag set to 'active' or 'hidden', something like that?

Comment: It's the best solution, but project already has lot of tables and I can't change them all.

Comment: That kind of response is often indicative of larger problems.

Comment: We need to exclude deleting info without saving it. With flag there are chance to delete row.